# How to identify if a scene has been opened by a certain segue in Swift?

Tags: swift, segue

I have a scene which I open with this segue.

```
//pass all retrived info from signup field over to the login scene to facilitate user experience
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showLoginController") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! LoginController;
        print("pass data over to next viewcontroller")
    }
}
```

This segue goes back to the Login screen where I want to set some values. However when the Login screen has not been loaded by segue "showLoginController", some fields should be empty.

How can I identify if LoginScene has been opened by a certain segue and set values accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `LoginController` view controller add this:

```
 var fromSegue = false
```

And in prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showLoginController") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! LoginController;
        svc.fromSegue = true
        print("pass data over to next viewcontroller")
    }
}
```

And then in your `LoginController` you can check `fromSegue`.

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can know the segue from the previous scene, in the sender scene, implement `prepareForSegue()` method to detect the sender